# Rotated QML Text: Position with baseline anchor

Tags: qt, qml

I need to position rotated `Text` elements relative to a rectangle. Here an example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  title: qsTr("Hello World")

  Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    x: 180
    y: 99
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "#b73131"

    Text {
      id: text1
      x: -112
      y: 85
      text: qsTr("Text")
      rotation: -90
      anchors.right: parent.left
      anchors.rightMargin: 20
      font.pixelSize: 12
    }

    Text {
        id: text2
        x: -46
        y: 160
        text: qsTr("Textg")
        font.pixelSize: 12
        rotation: -90
        anchors.right: parent.left
        anchors.rightMargin: 20
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would like that `text1` and `text2` share the same baseline (which does not happen in the above example because the `g` character goes below the baseline and thus the right edge is different for the two texts). How can I use the `baseline` anchor for rotated texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the rotation origin. I think this will give you the wanted result:

```
import QtQuick 2.7 
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  title: qsTr("Hello World")

  Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    x: 180
    y: 99
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "#b73131"

    Text {
      id: text1
      x: -112
      y: 85
      text: qsTr("Text")
      //rotation: -90
      anchors.right: parent.left
      anchors.rightMargin: 20
      font.pixelSize: 12
      transform: Rotation { origin.x: text1.width; origin.y: 0; angle: -90}
    }

    Text {
        id: text2
        x: -46
        y: 160
        text: qsTr("Textg")
        font.pixelSize: 12
        //rotation: -90
        anchors.right: parent.left
        anchors.rightMargin: 20
        transform: Rotation { origin.x: text2.width; origin.y: 0; angle: -90}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. Could you explain a bit what anchors mean if a rotation is performed? Also, If I would like to have the vertical center at the vertical center of the rectangle, what would I need to add?

Comment: anchors always effect the bounding box of your element. Just imagine a bounding rectangle around your rotated text.
I don't quite get what you mean by the vertical center! Can you clarify or post a picture of how you would like the end result to look like?

Comment: I meant: Do the anchors effect the bounding box of the element before or after rotation?
And the vertical center issue I had is solved...

Comment: after the rotation